# box2d:Move body with animation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

i am using box2d to developed iphone game.But i have not a lot of experience.I move a body to a location using this code

```
body->SetTransform(b2Vec2(posx2,posy2), 0);
```

and the body does move.But i need it to move with animation.in objective c i use UIView Animation to do similar type of things. can anyone tell how it possible in cocos2d box2d??

Comment: ok...i figure it out at last....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the way i did this.....

switch of the default tick method using /*...*/
and move the body manually...

```
b->SetTransform(b2Vec2(posx1, posy1), 0);
id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4 position:CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO)];
[sprite runAction:action];
```

another way:

don't comment off the tick....and inside tick instead of these:

```
myActor.position = CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
            myActor.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());
```

you can reset position with animation as like the above....